# compare arrays of two different lengths

Tags: java, android, arrays, similarity

I am developing a program on Android that will compare the similarity of Gestures using Gesture Points. I have two arrays like this:

```
gest_1 = [120,333,453,564,234,531]
gest_2 = [222,432,11,234,223,344,534,523,432,234]
```

I know there is no way to dynamically resize either one of the arrays, so is there any way for me to compare both these gestures using these arrays and return the similarity?

Note that the data in the arrays are just randomly typed out.

Comment: i think you need to define 'similarity' a bit more precisely.

Comment: I'm guessing that rather than the element-wise similarity (which all of the answers have given here), you want the similarity of the movement (i.e. rather than the elements being exactly the same, you want the difference between them to be similar [e.g. 1,10 is similar to 11,20])

Comment: Oops, sorry. I think by similarity means the elements in a particular array index should have the difference of nearly zero. For example: gest_1[0] - gest_2[0] = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  List similarities = new ArrayList();
  for(int i = 0; i < Math.max(gest_1.length, gest_2.length); i++){
    if (gest_1[i] == gest_2[i])
       similarities.add(gest_1[i];
  }
```

Comment: I think this is roughly the idea I am looking for. I don't need the values to be displayed anywhere. If values are almost the same, I will just add one count to a variable or something.

Answer (score 5):

Use a HashSet.  For the union of the two lists,

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>(); // Contains the union
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    hashSet.add(array1[i]);
for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    hashSet.add(array2[i]);
```

For the intersection of the two lists,

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();  // Contains the intersection
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    hashSet.add(array1[i]);
for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if(hashSet.contains(array2[i])) {
        list.add(array2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function it return array:-

```
public static String[] numSame (String[] list1, String[] list2) 
     {  
          int same = 0;  
          for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length-1; i++) 
          {  
             for(int j = 0; j <= list2.length-1; j++) 
             {  
                if (list1[i].equals(list2[j])) 
                {  
                    same++;  
                    break;  
                }  
             }  
          }  

          String [] array=new String[same];
          int p=0;
          for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length-1; i++) 
          {  
             for(int j = 0; j <= list2.length-1; j++) 
             {  
                if (list1[i].equals(list2[j])) 
                {  
                    array[p]=  list1[i]+"";
                    System.out.println("array[p] => "+array[p]);
                    p++;
                    break;  
                }  
             }  
          } 
          return array;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int temp = 0;
        int[] gest_1 = {120, 333, 453, 564, 234, 531};
        int[] gest_2 = {222, 432, 11, 234, 223, 344, 534, 523, 432, 234};
        ArrayList<Integer> g1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> g2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i : gest_1) {
            g1.add(i);
        }
        for (int i : gest_2) {
            g2.add(i);
        }
        for (int i : gest_1) {
            if (g2.contains(i)) {
                temp++;
            }
//            else{
//                break;
//            }
        }

        System.out.println(temp + " element(s) are equal ...");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does space matter? If not, you could store one of the arrays in a hashtable, and then iterate through the other array checking if the element is contained in the hashtable. This would be O(n) as opposed to O(nm), but this would also add to the size of the algorithm.

If you are unable to do such a thing, it would require two loops. The outer loop would increment the index of the first array after the inner loop has incremented through the entire second array checking if the elements are equal along the way. This could potentially be O(nm).

The above thoughts are assuming that when you say "similarities" it means that there are any elements in one array equal to any of the other elements in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

I have made mine with ArrayLists like this:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= NG1.size() - 1; a++) {
      int curNum1 = NG1.get(a);
      for (int b = 0; b <= NG2.size() - 1; b++) {
         int curNum2 = NG2.get(b);
         if (curNum1 == curNum2) {
           //Do stuff when two arrays are equal
         }
      }
   }
```

Knowing that the arrays are declared like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> NG1 = new ArrayList<>();//First number group
ArrayList<Integer> NG2 = new ArrayList<>();//Second number group
```

Answer (score -2):

We consider the two arrays like this
int[] array1={3,5,4,2,6,1,7,9,8};
        int[] array2={1,2,3,4,8};

Our aim is find the similar values.

```
    int[] res;

    if(array1.length>array2.length){
         res=new int[array2.length];
    }else{
        res=new int[array1.length];
    }

      int k=0;

    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
            {
            for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++)
                {
                    if(array1[i]==(array2[j]))
                        {
                        res[k]=array1[i];
                            k++;
                            break;

                       }

                }
            }

    for(int l=0;l<res.length;l++){


        System.out.print(res[l]);

    }
```

Comment: It looks as though you're breaking out of the loop after comparing the first element in `array2` to its counterpart in `array1`, except when `array2` is only 1 element long. I don't get what the length check against `j+` is even for here.