# Compare two String arrays , return matched Strings and mismatched Strings separately

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am developing an android application. I am trying to compare two string arrays and  return the matches , mismatches.
I tried couple of solutions but it's not working at all. I need matches and mismatches separately.

Here are the arrays with example data

```
String[] number_one = { "info@fn.ca" , "+122637867"  , "486" , "smbr" , "9946567" };

String[] number_two = { "+122637867" , "486" , "nrkZone"  , "smbr'};
```

Here is the example code i am working on.

```
          for(int n =0; n < number_one.length; n++){

            if(number_one[n] == number_two[n]){
                 Log.d("Cursor" ,number_one[n]);
            }else{
                 Log.d("Cursor" ,number_two[n]);
             }

           }
```

I want outputs like (Example data)

```
 Matched : +122637867 , 486 , smbr
 Mismatched :  info@fn.ca , nrkZone , 9946567
```

Comment: what do you exactly want as result?

Comment: Use "equals" to compare String values.Also, as your code is, you will only match tokens if they have the same position in the array.Is it what you want ?

Comment: No i wanna find the matched strings from the two arrays and unmatched strings too.. @HojjatImani

Comment: no he wants one string with +122637867, 486,smr and an other info@fn.ca, ETC.

Comment: @dacrovinunghi yes man :) you got it :)

Comment: you need 2 for loop each array

Comment: any examples @dacrovinunghi

Comment: @SijoJohn can you use a HashMap for this ?

Comment: how ? . any samples ?

Comment: Work on algorith (2 imbriqued loops ) and do some efforts (test code bellow)

Comment: This question is pretty good question and why it has a -1 Rep

Comment: Zachery gives you the right answer, do your job part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930540/compare-arrays-of-two-different-lengths?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I probably did more than I should have, and maybe even made it over complicated. But I'll let you guys decide that.

The first thing that I did was to use HashSets to store the matched and mismatched values. This is useful because they only store one of each value.

```
String[] number_one = { "info@fn.ca" , "+122637867"  , "486" , "smbr" , "9946567" };
String[] number_two = { "+122637867" , "486" , "nrkZone"  , "smbr"};


HashSet<String> matched = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> mismatched = new HashSet<String>();
```

Now I have quite a few for loops, this part I figure you could simplify into maybe just one. But alas, it works. Now as to *why*. Well, the way this code works is by *assuming* all of the values in the arrays have no matches until proven otherwise. So it simply puts all of them into the `mismatched` HashSet.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_one.length; i++) {
    mismatched.add(number_one[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < number_two.length; i++) {
    mismatched.add(number_two[i]);
}
```

Now you need to nest two for loops to iterate through both arrays, and in the process checking for any matches, and if there is one, it is added to the `matched` HashSet.

```
for(int n = 0; n < number_one.length; n++) {
       for (int m = 0; m < number_two.length; m++) {
           if(number_one[n].equals(number_two[m])){
            matched.add(number_one[n]);
           }
       }
   }
```

Now we simply remove all of the values that we know have matches from the `mismatched` variable, which already has ALL of the possible values. We are simply removing what we know matches.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matched.size(); i++) {
    mismatched.remove(matched.toArray()[i]);
}
```

And here we simply print them out in a semi-neat fashion.

```
System.out.print("Matched: ");
for (int i = 0; i < matched.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(matched.toArray()[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println("");
System.out.print("Mismatched: ");
for (int i = 0; i < mismatched.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(mismatched.toArray()[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: this one prints few matches only.

Comment: @SijoJohn What do you mean? It works fine for me. Either you are using it wrong or I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are two arrays in my android app . Some times one array would be larger than the second one. So the loop exits and print the first few matched elements , the rest of them will be printed with the unmatched. @zachery

Comment: That's what my code does, it considers everything to be unmatched until the code that checks for matches runs and then removes them. I encourage you to copy all my code and run it outside of android. In vanilla eclipse or whatever IDE you use (if any). And toy around with the two arrays at the top. @SijoJohn

Comment: but why android return first few matched elements ?.

Comment: I don't really have experience with android so I cannot answer that. I will tell you that my code does indeed work in plain Java. Unless someone else can help you you'll need to figure this out on your own. I'm willing to bet that the code before the print statements is completely fine either way, it's probably the error with printing on your part. Could you attach any code that you are using right now? @SijoJohn

Answer (score -1):

Try this code implemented using array.

```
    String[] number_one = { "info@fn.ca" , "+122637867"  , "486" , "smbr" , "9946567" };
    String[] number_two = { "+122637867" , "486" , "nrkZone"  , "smbr"};
    boolean mismatch=true;
    for(int i=0;i<number_one.length;i++){
        mismatch=true;
        for(int j=0;j<number_two.length;j++){
        if(number_one[i].equals(number_two[j])){
            System.out.println(number_one[i]+"Matches");
        mismatch=false;
        break;
        }
        }
    if(mismatch){
        System.out.println(number_one[i]+"Mis Matches");
    }
    }
```